# Extract partial matches string(words) between 2 columns in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, user-defined-functions

I have two columns like below, I need to extract a partial word that matches between the 2 columns and put this in a 3rd columns.

```
      Name1                              Name2
RED CURRY CHICKEN                 GREEN CURRY CHICKEN
BEEF WITH MINT LEAVES             BEEF WITH BASIL LEAVES
SWEET AND SOUND PORK              BACON AND EGG
FRIED RICE                        FRIED RICE
```

My expected result

```
      Name1                              Name2                     Partial Matches
RED CURRY CHICKEN                 GREEN CURRY CHICKEN               CHICKEN
BEEF WITH MINT LEAVES             BEEF WITH BASIL LEAVES            BEEF WITH LEAVES
SWEET AND SOUND PORK              BACON AND EGG                     AND
FRIED RICE                        FRIED RICE                        FRIED RICE
```

Comment: To do this with a formula is inefficient; you need vba for a sub procedure or user defined function.

Comment: in your first line of expected results, why isn't CURRY a partial match?

Comment: Sorry for the wrong type, and yes CURRY should show up in a result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this with a formula is inefficient; you need vba for a sub procedure or user defined function.

```
Function friedRice(str1 As String, str2 As String)
    Dim w As Long, words As Variant, tmp As String

    words = Split(str1, Chr(32))

    For w = LBound(words) To UBound(words)
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(words(w), Split(str2, Chr(32)), 0)) Then
            tmp = tmp & Chr(32) & words(w)
        End If
    Next w

    friedRice = Trim(tmp)

End Function
```

[image]